# Replace all keys in an array of dictionary in cocoa

Tags: cocoa, nsarray, nsdictionary

I have a mutable array that consist of array of dictionaries as:

```
NSArray *myArray    
({
    {
        "COL_1" = Jhon;
        "COL_2" = 01/27/13;
        "COL_3" = THAILAND;
        "COL_4" = 5000;
        "COL_5" = No;
    },
    {
        "COL_1" = Peter;
        "COL_2" = 01/27/13;
        "COL_3" = US;
        "COL_4" = 4000;
        "COL_5" = No;
    }
 })
```

All dictionaries in the array have the same keys. I want to replace the existing keys with a new set of keys that will come from a NSArray. The final array should be like -

```
NSArray *myArray    
({
    {
        "A" = Jhon;
        "B" = 01/27/13;
        "C" = THAILAND;
        "D" = 5000;
        "E" = No;
    },
    {
        "A" = Peter;
        "B" = 01/27/13;
        "C" = US;
        "D" = 4000;
        "E" = No;
    }
 })
```

I do not want a nested for loop in which i have to iterate overs each elements in the array and again for each dictionary, iterating over each key , to change the keys.
What I did is as follow:

```
NSArray *myDictFnalKeys = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"A",@"B",@"C",@"D",@"E",nil];  // Here we have set our own keys which will replace the existing keys .
NSMutableArray *myNewArray = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease]; //create a new mutable dictionary
for (id myArrayInstance in array) {
            NSDictionary *myNewDict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjects:[myArrayInstance allObjects] forKeys:myDictFnalKeys]; // copy the object values from old dictionary and keys from the new array.
            [myNewArray addObject:myNewDict];
    }
```

The problem is the values for the dictionaries are not coming in proper order. [myArrayInstance allObjects] is not returning the proper order so the final array is not in proper order. Its coming like-

```
NSMutableArray *newArray
({
    {
        A = "01/27/13";
        B = No;
        C = Jhon;
        D = 5000;
        E = THAILAND;
    },
    {
        A = "01/27/13";
        B = No;
        C = Peter;
        D = 4000;
        E = US;
    }
```

})

Comment: Dictionaries are unordered, what did you expect?

Comment: My objective was to replace the old keys with new keys.. I followed that approach thinking the dictionary will return values in ordered way. Is there any approach to achieve the required functionality.

Comment: NSMutableArray *myNewArray = [NSMutableArray array]; //create a new mutable dictionary (that's auto-released)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're almost there, the only issue is the call to `allObjects` which as you found returns the objects in some arbitrary order. Instead define an array of your original keys:

```
NSArray *originalKeys = @[@"COL_1", @"COL_2", @"COL_3", @"COL_4", @"COL_5"];
```

where the elements are in the same order as the replacement in your `myDictFnalKeys`. Now replace the call to `allObjects` with:

```
[myDict objectsForKeys:originalKeys notFoundMarker:NSNull.null]
```

This will return an array of objects matching the keys *in order* found in `originalKeys` (if a key is missing then the result array will contain whatever `notFoundMarker` is - `NSNull.null` in this case).

Do that and your code will work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'objectsForKeys:notFoundMarker:' for getting the values in the requested order. Pass [NSNULL null] as the second argument. (This really does not matter, all the values are present in the dictionary and you are not trying get the values for a undefined key.)